# Having problems using parameters of a function to display a message

Tags: jquery, function, parameters

```javascript
function Seleccionar(indice, tipo, nombrecampo, clave) {
   Isselccionar = indice;
   if(esTexto(nombrecampo)) {
       if (tipo==="P") {
           tipo = "Pacientes";
       } else {
           tipo = "Medicos";
       }
   $("#" + nombrecampo).html(tipo+[indice]+calve);
   }
}
```

the result of `$("#"+nombrecampo)` is displaying the parameters as strings and is not displaying the things in the following way:

```
/*$("#campo").html(Medico[2].nombre);
```

parameters values:

```
nombrecampo "campo"
tipo "Medico"
indice 2
clave=nombre
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your if statement for something like the following:

```
if (esTexto(nombreCampo)) {
    $('#' + nombreCampo).html(Medicos[indice][clave]);
} else {
    $('#' + nombreCampo).html(Pacientes[indice][clave]);
}
```

Your overall function should look like this:

```js
var Medicos = [{
  id: "000001",
  nombre: "Juan Perez",
  especialidad: "Medicina General",
  contraseña: "1234c",
  tipo: 1
}, {
  id: "000002",
  nombre: "Gorge Molina",
  especialidad: "Medicina General",
  contraseña: "1234d",
  tipo: 1
}];

function esTexto(nombreCampo) {
  //Here goes your logic
  return true;
}

function seleccionar(indice, nombreCampo, clave) {
  if (esTexto(nombreCampo)) {
    $('#' + nombreCampo).html(Medicos[indice][clave]);
  } else {
    $('#' + nombreCampo).html(Pacientes[indice][clave]);
  }
}

seleccionar(1, 'campo', 'nombre');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="campo"></div>
```

Comment: The thing is that Medicos is a Array with objects and i want to access to the propety clave of the index indice from the Array Medicos||Pacientes

Comment: That's what my snippet is doing, isn't it? Have you tried it? What is not working for you?

Comment: Yes i tried but it isnt working, here is the array i want to acess to:                                     var Medicos=[
   {
    id:"000001",
    nombre:"Juan Perez",
    especialidad:"Medicina General",
    contraseña:"1234c",
    tipo:1
    },
    {
    id:"000002",
    nombre:"Gorge Molina",
    especialidad:"Medicina General",
    contraseña:"1234d",
    tipo:1
    }
];

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! it worked i have one more question if if it doesn't bother you about the link

Comment: The link to the function seleccionar is running automatically without selecting the link https://ibb.co/dpaEKd